# Which desktop and mobile wallets support watch only addresses for EOS?

Tags: accounts, wallet, address

I have an account and want to setup a watch only wallet address. Is there a desktop or mobile wallet that lets me just load up an address but not the private key? I have my private key on a paper wallet.

Comment: not quite what you're asking for but maybe this tool could be helpful to watch activity on your account https://eosauthority.com/alerts

Comment: I want to be able to just be able to load up my EOS account on my wallet without loading the private key so I can view all the transactions coming in, but not be able to send anything out. This is for cold storage purposes.